# Counting arrangements of the numbers $1$–$10$ in a circle such that each number is not greater than the sum of its neighbors

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

> How many ways are there to arrange the numbers $1$–$10$ in a circle such that each number is not greater than the sum of the two numbers adjacent to it?

My Progress: Not much really. When I can solve a problem, I can solve it, and if I can't, it's usually because I don't know how to start.

I thought a little bit about what would be an automatic no.

10 can't have two numbers less than 6 next to it.
1 and 2 can't have a number in between them unless that number is 3.

etc... Clearly this doesn't work. I need to find a way to just straight up count the ones that work and not subtract the ones that don't work.

So I looked at recursion.

So for 1 there is 1 way
For 2 there is 1 way (rotation)
For 3 there is 2 ways: 1,2,3 and 1,3,2
For 4 there are however many there are such that 4 isn't between 1 and 2.

But past that it already gets very messy. Does anybody have a slick solution?

Comment: The only weapons that I know of are [1] the direct approach, [2] recursion, and [3] inclusion-exclusion.  As your posting indicates, and I agree with, both [1] and [2] are problematic.  Unfortunately, in my opinion, so is [3].  So, I don't see any elegant analytical approach.   Maybe someone else does.

Comment: What is the source of the problem? Is it a programming problem?

Comment: Bruteforce gives 1,2,4,14,52,258,1424,9204,65650 for counts from 2 to 10 if we consider arrangements that differ by rotation to be the same, multimple by $n$ otherwise. Neither sequence is in OEIS.

Comment: Well.. seems like this might just be one of those problems that just needs to get bashed.

Comment: @quasi I enjoy writing problems for mock AIME's and such and thought this was a potential candidate (although I couldn't figure it out haha).